# yii basic pagination doesn't work

Tags: yii, pagination

I am trying to list results with basic pagination, but it doesnt work. I see the pagination bar but all results list in one shot not page by page. When I click on a number nothing change.

This is my first pagination try. I thought i made a simple mistake but coudnt find it. I just tried a simple tutorial like in this link. 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination

Any ideas?

Controller:

```
    $Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $Criteria->order = "creation_date desc";
    $resultSet=MyTable::model()->findAll($Criteria);
    $count=  count($resultSet);

    $pages = new CPagination($count);
    $pages->applyLimit($Criteria);
    $pages->pageSize = 7;

    $this->renderPartial('index',array('resultSet'=>$resultSet,'pages' => $pages));
```

View:

```
$this->widget('CLinkPager', array('pages' => $pages, "cssFile" => false));

foreach ($resultSet as $x => $res):
    echo $res->name;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you've got `pageSize` being set after your `applyLimit()` call. This means the query will use the default of (I think) 30. Which may be everything if you expect 7 per page?

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But there is another trick,  the line ´$pages = new CPagination($count);´ should be before the resultset generation.

Comment: Glad it worked, you can click the tick on the left of my answer to mark it as accepted. Thanks.